# Not sure how to do a while loop in this situation

Tags: java

I am writing a program to take the input for a sequence

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class FibonacciCode {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter a number");

    int count, number0 = 0, number1 = 1, loop = 0;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    count = userInput.nextInt();

    while(loop > count)
    {
        System.out.print(number0 + ", ");

        int sum = number0 + number1;
        number0 = number1;
        number1 = sum;
        loop++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you have a couple of answers. Since you are new, here's what to do next. If any of the solutions posted solve your problem, upvote and accept that solution. That will change the answered status of this question as well as make it easier for others to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a usable implementation:

```
public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean orderCompleted = false;
        while(!orderCompleted) {
            printMenu();
            String orderString = a.nextLine();
            int order = Integer.parseInt(orderString);
            int total = 0;
            if(order == 1) {
            } else if(order == 2) {
            } else if(order == 3) {
            } else if(order == 4) {
            } else if(order == 5) {
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to order more? Press 'y' to continue or 'n' to finish order.");
            orderString = a.nextLine();
            if(orderString.equals("n")){
                orderCompleted = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hess Burgers");
        System.out.println("1- Cheeseburger.............$7");
        System.out.println("2- Barbeque Burger..........$8");
        System.out.println("3- Southwestern Burger......$9");
        System.out.println("4- Bacon Cheeseburger.......$10");
        System.out.println("5- Double Stack Burger......$11");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Please enter your order selection:");
    }
}
```

I pulled the menu printing to a separate method, and re-used scanner `a` as well as re-using the orderString. The while loop checks a `completedOrder` boolean flag, so that it can be used to do completion tasks prior to exiting the order loop if need be.

Answer (score 1):

import java.util.Scanner;
public class FibonacciCode {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter a number");

    int count, number0 = 0, number1 = 1, loop = 0;

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    count = userInput.nextInt();

    while(loop > count)
    {
        System.out.print(number0 + ", ");

        int sum = number0 + number1;
        number0 = number1;
        number1 = sum;
        loop++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Java is saying that continue is an error by saying "Syntax error on token "continue", invalid VariableDeclaratorId"

Comment: @PleaseHelp Fixed, that was dumb of me.. `continue` is a reserved word, so it can't be the name of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

A while loop does whatever is in the block as long as the condition is true, in your case, you are simply repeating `order = b.nextInt()` until something other than 'y' is given as input

```
while (continuePlay= b.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase ("y")) {
        order = b.nextInt(); // This is inside the block
    }
```

you should use a `do while` loop instead, like so:

```
do{
    System.out.println("Welcome to Hess Burgers");
    System.out.println("1- Cheeseburger.............$7");
    System.out.println("2- Barbeque Burger..........$8");
    System.out.println("3- Southwestern Burger......$9");
    System.out.println("4- Bacon Cheeseburger.......$10");
    System.out.println("5- Double Stack Burger......$11");
    System.out.println("                               ");
    System.out.print("Please enter your order selection:");

    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    int order = a.nextInt();

    int total = 0;
    boolean continuePlay = true;

    if (order == 1 ) {

    } else if (order == 2) {

    } else if (order == 3) {

    } else if (order == 4) {

    } else if (order == 5) {
    }
    Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Would you like to order more? Press 'y' to continue or 'n' to finish order.");
    } while (continuePlay= b.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase ("y"));
```

Also I'd recommend reading some basic programming books or tutorials instead of going directly to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations of books/tutorials? It would be a huge help if you could point me in the right direction.